# What data analysis would be best to use for my Masters Dissertation?

Tags: crossover-study

I will be conducting an intervention where I will be comparing the effects of Kinesiology Tape and Placebo tape on CECS in motorcycle racers.

A reading will be taken pre tape application of both arms, and then readings will be taken again with Kinesiology tape and again with Placebo tape with a grip strength dynamometer, what test will be best to compare all this data?

Please help

Comment: What is the outcome?  What are you trying to determine?

Comment: If kinesiology has a greater effect than placebo, so if the grip strength is higher with that application, does that make sense?

Comment: So the outcome is grip strength?  How is grip strength being measured?  Do you want to control for any variables?  I imagine men have better grip strength than women for example.

Comment: Its only men that will be in the study, being measured with a grip strength dynamometer, 3 testing conditions, no tape, placebo and kinesiology

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've said in the comments, an ANCOVA might be appropriate.

This essentially boils down to doing a linear regression controlling for the pre-tape measurement of grip strength.  You can control for the placebo/kin tape through an indicator variable in your regression.  The relevant statistical test will be done by most statistical software automatically, so you would only need to look at the coefficient which represents in the subject received placebo or not.

The best analysis would depend on how the data are distributed given a pre-measurement and intervention.  I'm not familiar enough with the field enough to say if you will experience homogeneity of variance, but if you do then you will likely need to think of a different approach.  For now, ANCOVA sounds like a good first crack at the problem.